# Configuring mail sender using Java configuration in Spring Cloud AWS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-aws

I want to send emails using Amazon SES, Spring Cloud AWS and Spring Boot 2.1.5.

In the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_sending_mails), it provides XML to configure the mail sender. Is there any way to use Java config instead of XML?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work, here's what I did.

1. Build dependencies

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses'
```

2. Config bean

```
@Configuration
public class AwsConfig {

    @Bean
    public AmazonSimpleEmailService amazonSimpleEmailService(AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider) {
         return AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
            .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MailSender mailSender(AmazonSimpleEmailService ses) {
        return new SimpleEmailServiceMailSender(ses);
    }    
}
```

3. NotificationService

```
@Service
public class NotificationService {

    @Autowired
    private MailSender mailSender;

    public void sendMailMessage() {
        SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        simpleMailMessage.setFrom("sender@mail.com");
        simpleMailMessage.setTo("to@mail.com");
        simpleMailMessage.setSubject("test subject");
        simpleMailMessage.setText("test text");
        this.mailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);
    }
}
```

4. application.yml

```
cloud:
  aws:
    credentials:
      accessKey: <YOUR_ACCESS_KEY>
      secretKey: <YOUR_SECRET_KEY>
    stack:
      auto: false
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the config file to this and it works fine.I hope it helps

```
@Configuration
public class AwsMailConfig {

  @Bean
  public AmazonSimpleEmailService amazonSimpleEmailService() {

    BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials =
        new BasicAWSCredentials(
            <AWS_ACCESS_KEY>,<AWS_SECRET_KEY>);

    return AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAWSCredentials))
        .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public JavaMailSender javaMailSender(AmazonSimpleEmailService amazonSimpleEmailService) {
    return new SimpleEmailServiceJavaMailSender(amazonSimpleEmailService);
  }
}
```